# Беспрырывное вращение квадрата на CSS3

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animation

Вот код html

```
  .square {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation: squne 4s ease;
    -moz-animation:    squne 4s ease;
    -o-animation:      squne 4s ease;
    animation:         squne 4s ease;
}

@keyframes squne {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Пока не нашел ошибку. Нужно чтобы элемент .square беспрырывно плано вращался вокруг своей оси. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.square {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: squne 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes squne {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```